# Component using a custom hook is not rerendered when the data inside the custom hook changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having issue with the "user" of my custom hook not rerendering after the data in the hook has been updated.

The useEffect hook inside of the custom hook useFilter() is ran when the selectedCategories state is updated (as it should). However, the component that uses the data (feedback) from the useFilter hook is not rerendered when the data updates.

Here is the useFilter:

```
export function useFilters() {
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState<any>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      //Fetches data from an API
      setFeedback(data || []);
    };

    fetch();
  }, [selectedCategories]);

  return {
    setSelectedCategories,
    feedback,
  };
}
```

And here is the "user" of the hook:

```
export default function Inbox() {
  const { feedback } = useFilters();

  return (
    <Container>
      {feedback.map((id: number) => (
        <Link href={`/feedback/${id}`}>
          <InboxItem feedbackId={id} key={id />
        </Link>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I've tried spreading the new data into a new array inside the useEffect to maybe trigger a rerender, but to no avail

```
setSelectedCategories([...data])
```

Comment: You should call `setSelectedCategories` inside component that uses `feedback`. Otherwise you need a global store or context.

When you call `useFilters`, it creates a new state (selectedCategories, feedback), and this state is different for every component where useFilters is called.

Comment: When you use `useFilters`, `feedback` is always an empty array which is why it doesn't work. You are probably calling `setSelectedCategories` using a different instance of `useFilters` which is the same the other comment is saying.